# Getting youtube link element from source code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am observing http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=kohli and trying to lookup video urls.

Anchor tag contains youtube link, but inside dictionary which I want to extract.

```
redditFile = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bing.com/videos?q="+urllib.quote_plus(word))
redditHtml = redditFile.read()
redditFile.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(redditHtml)
productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'dg_u'})
for div in productDivs:
    print div.find('a')['vrhm'] #This element contains youtube urls but print does not display it
    if div.find('div', {"class":"vthumb", 'smturl': True}) is not None:
        print div.find('div', {"class":"vthumb", 'smturl': True})['smturl'] #this gives link to micro video
```

How can I get youtube link from `a` tag and `vrhm` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) to load a a dictionary from json string.

The `for` loop can be modified as

```
>>> productDivs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'dg_u'})
>>> for div in productDivs:
...     a_dict = json.loads( div.a['vrhm'] )
...     print a_dict['p']
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWbrWI3PBss
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWbrWI3PBss
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbTx2Fjth-0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pB1Kjx-eheY
..
..
```

**What it does?**

- `div.a['vrhm']` extracts the `vrhm` attribute of the immediate `a` child of the `div`.
- `a_dict = json.loads( div.a['vrhm'] )` loads the json string and creates the dictionary `a_dict`.
- `print a_dict['p']` The `a_dict` is a python dictionary. Use them as you usually do.

Comment: thanks but this still does not print youtube url, rather article link. can you please add full code snippet you tried

Comment: What do you mean by article link? I see links to youtube in the output. :/

Comment: This is the code snippet I tired. I copied the div from the source and and tested them